Workday: is there an API or other programmatic way to download the output files from an integration event?
In the Workday system, some integrations produce output files when they run.  You can go into Workday's user interface to download these files manually, for example, by running the "Integration Events" report and viewing the background process of the integration when it finishes.  Is there some kind of API or other way that would allow us to download those output files programmatically?  Or can we only do this manually through the user interface?  Thanks.
I have been able to successfully query the "Integration Events" report through Postman, but for the integration event, the query results provide a "Background_Process_Instance_ID" instead of a direct link to the background process; I assume the "Background_Process_Instance_ID" might be useful in further requests, but I don't know what endpoints I can call.

Using this  old-school technique : From the WD integration send the file to a SFTP site and you can download from there using a script or a program.

That's definitely worth considering, but I was hoping for a way to fully automate the process.

I've figured out a solution.  First, I use the integration's integration_system_id to query the list of events for that integration using Workday's Get_Integration_Events SOAP webservice; the record for the event I'm interested in will contain the background_process_id for that event.  Next, I use that background_process_id to query the list of documents for that event from the Get_Event_Documents SOAP webservice; this list contains (among other data) the document_ids of the event's documents.  Finally, I use the document_id of the file I want to actually download that file from Workday using Workday's cc-blobitory api (I got that from stackoverflow here).
